# Star Trek episode with a scene where Data has to choose between three different time anomalies with him in each

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

What is the episode with a scene where Data has to choose between three different time anomalies with him in each?

Data asks which one is the correct time frame in the scene and having chosen the right one the crisis is resolved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [TNG: We'll Always Have Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We%27ll_Always_Have_Paris_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)).

The scene with the three Datas (complete with "*It's me!*" contraction fail) is below.

Comment: yeap that's the one - now I can go watch, thanks

Comment: I always wondered how mid-Data knew he was the one in the right timeframe.  Like I saw no evidence beyond "he's one in the middle."

Comment: @starpilotsix - Worth asking as a question

Comment: Possibly because the middle Data represented the present. The other Datas represented the past and future.

Comment: according to the wiki link this scene was not  written by the screen writers due to stikes so there may have been a bit of creativity going on here though Ham Sandwich's idea seems most plausable.

Comment: @onepound - you can see the original ending (as written) here; http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/124.txt

Comment: @Valorum  Scaning through this script it has quite a bit more charged exchanges between Manheim and Picard than the screen version I watched yesterday and quite a bit more drama using Worf and Geodi in the patching up 'time' scene - very interesting probably they could not fit all that into 45min. Nevertheless the three time frame scene is the one that stuck in my memory more than anything else about the episode!